# Azure Lake Store : missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin from response header

Tags: azure, cors, azure-data-lake, azure-management-api

When trying to call my azure data lake store space and list all directories , It fails to return any results during to missing CORS .The problem that I can't find any way to give the Azure DatalakeStore the CORS policy ( Not the same as Azure Storage )

Any workaround or solution for this ?

Comment: What code are you using?  What precise error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the services in Azure still doesn't have CORS support (like DocumentDB and as you have experienced seems for ADLS as well). One thing that can be tried before the same is provided by azure is to use APIM (Azure API Management Gateway). I tried this where i have on-boarded DocumentDB REST API's on APIM and used the end-point from APIM on client side and it worked.  Check the links below for setting up APIM and enabling CORS

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/7689d277-8abe-472a-a78c-e6d4bd43455d#CORS

Comment: Thank you !! I have solved the issue with a similar solution as you suggested by calling the rest service from my server part not directly from the client.