# Azure DataLake File Download From Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, cross-domain, azure-data-lake

I was trying to download the file from azure data lake storage. it's working on c# side using Rest API. but it's not working in a java script.

My Sample c# code is

//Get Access Token

```
public DataLakeAccessToken ServiceAuth(string tenatId, string clientid, string clientsecret)
{

        var authtokenurl = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/token", tenatId);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var model = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","client_credentials"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource","https://management.core.windows.net/"),//Bearer
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",clientid),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret",clientsecret),

            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(model);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(authtokenurl, content).Result;
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var accessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataLakeAccessToken>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                return accessToken;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }


        }
    }
```

File Download Code is

```
 public void DownloadFile(string srcFilePath, ref string destFilePath)
    {

        int i = 0;
        var folderpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(destFilePath);
        var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(destFilePath);
        var extenstion = Path.GetExtension(destFilePath);
        Increment:
        var isfileExist = File.Exists(destFilePath);
        if (isfileExist)
        {
            i++;
            destFilePath = folderpath+filename + "_" + i + "_" + extenstion;
            goto Increment;
         }
            string DownloadUrl = "https://{0}.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/{1}?op=OPEN&read=true";
        var fullurl = string.Format(DownloadUrl, _datalakeAccountName, srcFilePath);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accesstoken.access_token);
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync(fullurl).Result;
                using (var fs = new FileStream(destFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                   response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs).Wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

first i was Generate the token using client credentials and the token based download file using path example https://mydatalaksestore.azuredatalaksestore.net/myfolder/myfile i pass myfolder/myfile in source path and destFilePath file name based download the file

in javascript i was get the accesstoken from my api server and send the request for mydatalakestore it's throw error for  cross orgin for localhost:8085 like this

[image]

Any one know how to download the datalake store file using Javascript from Client Side using Access Token without cross orgin error

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693452/azure-lake-store-missing-access-control-allow-origin-from-response-header, it seems CORS is not supported for Azure Data Lake.

Comment: Hi umasankar..i have a question related to Download file code. I am trying to download the file to local drive and I am getting the error "The access token is not provided in the 'Authorization' header". However I am passing the Access token. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: @code_blue If you are trying to download you pass the access token in request header. In above code "ServiceAuth" method.i was generated the access token and "DownloadFile" method i was passed the access token in my web request. this way you should pass the access token download your file to local drive using the way of client credential flow.